# Can't enable or disable jquery menubar items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using a jquery ui menubar. So far I had good results, but I'm trying to programmatically enable and disable menubar items(e.g. file->exit). This just doesn't work for me.

Part of the html definition of the menubar is:

```
 <div class="Dashboard">
  <ul id="MainMenubar" class="menubar-icons">
    <li>
      <a href="#File">File</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled" id="logout"><a href="#Logout">Logout</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#LoadUsers">Load users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Exit">Exit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now when I call: `$( "#logout" ).menubar( "enable" );`
, I get the following error: "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on menubar prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'". I don't understand, because the menubar is initialize long before, when the page is loaded.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Where is the id Logout? You are disabling some element on the page, not the link!

Comment: Ah, unless you're talking about [this menubar plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-menubar/). In that case, @Plynx's answer is right (an URL to that plugin would have helped in your question).

Answer (score 1):

`#Logout` is an HREF for a URL in your code, not an ID. You need to assign the HTML attribute `id="Logout"` to some element in order to reference it the way you are doing here.

For example:

```
<li id="logout"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
```

```
$("#logout").menubar("enable");
```

Comment: Answer is wrong. the #Logout points to an element on the page, you just broke that.

Comment: Even if I change <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#Logout">Logout</a></li>

Comment: @nvdstruis The id has to be on the `li`. You can do `<li class="ui-state-disabled" id="logout">` if you want.

Comment: Hello Plynx, I tried this, but then I get the error: "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on menubar prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'"

Comment: @nvdstruis Somewhere in your code you have something like `$("#MainMenubar").menubar(something);` You want to put anything about enabling/disabling in your javascript *after* this line.

Comment: @Plynx I do not have a statement like that in my code. Should I?

Comment: @nvdstruis Probably. If you're using the plugin linked to in the comments, for sure you must have it. As for what the `something` is, it could be a long list of options in braces, or nothing at all.

Comment: I still get the error ""Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on menubar prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'"". Makes no sense to me, as the menubar is long visible before I try to enable the item.

Comment: @nvdstruis At this point, you might want to try testing things out by putting this enable/disable event into a button press to see if you have a race condition. But you might also want to invest the time into making a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ that reproduces your problem so we can all help debug.